Apache no realiza reverse proxy al puerto 3000
A chatGTP lo tengo ya en bucle :)
Voy al grano, a ver si alguien puede orientarme:
Tengo un back en node+express usando el puerto 3000 deplegado en mi servidor, si accedo a http://api.dominio.com:3000/ funciona, me da una respuesta que he preparado correctamente (Lo tengo arrancado con pm2).
Según he leido, al usar LetsEncrypt, solo funciona bajo el puerto 80 o 443 y para que la aplicación de express se cargue con https, tengo que hacer un reverse proxy con apache o nginx.
Partiendo de aquí, he optado por apache y en el archivo "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/api.dominio.com.conf" he agregado esto:
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName api.dominio.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/

</VirtualHost>

Y he reiniciado apache.
El resultado es que en https://api.dominio.com/ me carga un index.html que hay en blanco en vez de la aplicación express (que si lo sigue haciendo en http).
¿Qué me falta?
